# C Beginner - Copying a char *array to another char *array

Tags: c

I've been struggling with this for a stupidly long amount of time.
Basically, I need to copy an array of char pointers to another array of char pointers.

Right now, I have the function:

```
void copyArray(char *source[], char *destination[]) {
    int i = 0;

    do {
        destination[i] = malloc(strlen(source[i]));
        memcpy(destination[i], source[i], strlen(source[i]));
    } while(source[i++] != NULL);
}
```

This results in a segmentation fault. Could someone please help?

Thanks!

EDIT: sample program

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Copy the contents of one array into another
void copyArray(char *source[], char *destination[]){
    // printf("In copy array");
    int i = 0;

    do {
        destination[i] = malloc(strlen(source[i]));
        memcpy(destination[i], source[i], strlen(source[i]));
    } while(source[i++] != NULL);
}

void addToHistory(char *history[][40], char *args[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        copyArray(history[i], history[i-1]);
    }
    i = 0;
    copyArray(args, history[0]);
}

int main(void){
    char *history[10][40];
    char *args[40];

    history[0][0] = NULL;

    args[0] = "ls";
    args[1] = NULL;

    addToHistory(history, args);
}
```

Comment: are you certain that the array source[] has a final NULL value?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Can you show a full (but small) example program which demonstrates this problem?

Comment: For my purposes, I do know that source will end with a final NULL value (it is the way the string is parsed in my program). I am working on a simple shell program and I uploaded a small test-code snippet..

Comment: Please check the answer for your qn, here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565328/how-to-copy-an-array-of-char-pointer-to-another-in-c?noredirect=1#comment60740174_36565328

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the last element in the `source` array is `NULL`, before you pass it to `copyArray`.
2. In `copyArray`, put the `while` instead of the `do`, and increment `i` only **at the end** of the loop.

Instead all of the above, you can simply change `i++` to `++i` in function `copyArray`.

But it will crash if the first element in the `source` array passed to this function is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an off-by-one error:

```
do {
    destination[i] = malloc(strlen(source[i]));
    memcpy(destination[i], source[i], strlen(source[i]));
} while(source[i++] != NULL);
               ^^^
```

You check if i **was** NULL *after* you already used it, and then end the loop.  Try replacing it with

```
} while (source[++i] != NULL);           // or while (source[++i]), for short
```

You can try logging a short message after each iteration to see where the code faults.

Edit:  Is there a reason you are using `memcpy()` (which will not copy the terminating `'\0'`) rather than `strcpy()` (which will)?

(Note to @wildplasser: I believe `strdup()` may not be standard C).

Answer (score 0):

```
void copyArray(char *source[], char *destination[]) {

    while ((*destiantion = *source)) {
        *destination++ = strdup( *source++ );
    }
}
```

BTW: it is common to make destination the first argument, just as in `strcpy()`

```
void copyArray(char *destination[], char *source[]) { ... }
```