# How to copy an array of char pointer to another in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to store an array of char pointer to another array of char pointer. I am getting segmentation fault for the same.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{   
    int argcCpy = argc;
    char* argvCpy[10] = {};

    for(argcCpy = argc; argcCpy>0; argcCpy--)
    {   
        argvCpy[argcCpy] = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[argcCpy]));
        memcpy(argvCpy[argcCpy], argv[argcCpy], strlen(argv[argcCpy]));
        printf("\nCount: %d, string: %s", argcCpy, argvCpy[argcCpy]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I spent more than enough time to make this work but I am not able to do it. Also, the same kind of question is already asked which is also left unanswered. If anybody can let me know the working code for the same, it would be really so helpful.

Hoping this to be answered.

Link of the similar question left out unawnsered -- [C Beginner - Copying a char *array to another char *array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290255/c-beginner-copying-a-char-array-to-another-char-array)

Thanks.

Comment: What is `argvCpy[0]` supposed to hold in your program? Garbage?

Comment: Why would I need a variable to hold a garbage value? Has been initialized !! Thanks for the comments :) @Lundin I need this var to hold the *argv array..

Comment: My point is: your code doesn't copy anything into index 0 so it just sits there taking up space. This in turn suggests that either the array size in incorrect or the loop is not correctly written.

Comment: I need the values from arg 2 @Lundin.. Hence storing it in argvCpy from arg2 onwards.

Comment: But this code stores argv[x] to argv[1] into your array, in backwards order. So how many arguments do you need? 8? Then why declare an array of 10?

Comment: What do you mean by argv[x] ? @Lundin

Comment: The magic number that equals the number of arguments needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int argcCpy = argc;
    char* argvCpy[10] = {};

    if (argc > 9)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = argc; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (argv[i] == NULL)
        {
            argvCpy[i] = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            argvCpy[i] = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
            if (argvCpy[i] != NULL)
            {
                strcpy(argvCpy[i], argv[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= argcCpy; i++)
    {
        if (argvCpy[i] != NULL)
        {
            printf("Count: %d, string: %s\n", i, argvCpy[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Count: %d, string is null\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check argc is not too high.
`argv[argc]` is NULL, take this into account.
Use `strcpy`, and allocate enough room for the ending `\0`.

Edit: Second `for` loop to show content.

Comment: Superb. Thanks a lot for your timely help. Its working. @jdarthenay

Comment: It is not obvious why they would want to store the program name `argv[0]` in the array though.

Comment: @ Lundin If you don't want it, set it to NULL, but do not leave it that way like in OP's code. Or index argvCpy so that `argvCpy[i]` stands for `argv[i + 1]`

Comment: @jdarthenay, Is there any ways that I can use the array out of the else without segmentaion fault..??

Comment: @Denise you should not get a segmentation fault. What are you doing exactly to get one?

Comment: @jdarthenay I am trying to do this: `int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{ int argcCpy = argc; int i = argc; char* argvCpy[10] = {};
    if (argc > 9)
    { return 1; }
    for(argcCpy = argc; argcCpy>0; argcCpy--)
    { if (argv[argcCpy] == NULL)
        { argvCpy[argcCpy] = NULL;  }
        else
        { argvCpy[argcCpy] = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[argcCpy]));
            strcpy(argvCpy[argcCpy], argv[argcCpy]); }
    }
    printf("\nCount: %d, string: %s\n", argcCpy, argvCpy[argcCpy]);
    return 0;
}` & I get seg fault

Comment: @Denise Do you realize you are trying to print content of `argvCpy[-1]`? I am updating my answer.

Comment: Yes,. before was trying to print it in a for loop where `i = argc` hence I was trying to access argvCpy[2] for the cmd : './a.out hi' and hence was getting seg fault. Thank you once again now I am able to print the same :) @jdarthenay

Comment: `argvCpy[i] = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[i]));`?  How many bytes does `"string"` contain?  That should be `argvCpy[i] = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);`  That's also a likely cause of a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Thanks, that was an error introduced back at first edit.

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate one byte more for the terminating NUL:

Change

```
 malloc(strlen(argv[argcCpy]);
```

to

```
 malloc(strlen(argv[argcCpy] + 1);
```

and you also must copy one byte more with `memcpy`

Change

```
 memcpy(argvCpy[argcCpy], argv[argcCpy], strlen(argv[argcCpy]));
```

to

```
 memcpy(argvCpy[argcCpy], argv[argcCpy], strlen(argv[argcCpy]) + 1);
```

BTW you can replace

```
 memcpy(argvCpy[argcCpy], argv[argcCpy], strlen(argv[argcCpy]) + 1);
```

by

```
 strcpy(argvCpy[argcCpy], argv[argcCpy]);
```

which is simpler and more clear.

And last but not least replace

```
for(argcCpy = argc; argcCpy>0; argcCpy--)
```

by

```
for(argcCpy = argc - 1; argcCpy>0; argcCpy--)
```

The last element of the `argv` array is `argv[argc-1]`.

But be aware that you'll run into problems if you have more then 10 command line arguments.

Comment: Michael, it still outputs as segmentation fault.

Comment: Even simpler (since you are using malloc for memory allocation anyway): argvCpy[argcCpy] = strdup (argv[argcCpy]);

Comment: Two strings walk into a bar. One says "I'll have a beer, please794(*&%#$)${". The other says, "You'll have to excuse my friend, he's not null terminated."
(That's one way of never forgetting again!)

Comment: Thank you lots @Mike & Micheal Walz